# Error trying to run WCF Test Client on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, wcftestclient

I have a C# Web Application that work as a Gateway, with some wcf services created on it.
If i set any of the .svc files as the Start Page and try to run it, the WCF Test Client load, the green bar loads to half, and then the App crashes without even reaching the source code.

The weirdest thing, if i switch to Visual Studio 2013, the app and the WCF Test Client runs normally. The VS 2013 is the Professional version, and the 2015 is Community.

Below the generic error it generates:

[image]

Comment: You can enable message logging in server side and check what is happening! May be visual studio 2015 is not able to recognise the path of wcf test client.

Comment: WCF Test Client starts, it's green bar loads to half, and then everything crashes.
Theres a trace on system.diagnostics, but there is nothing there.

Comment: What does it say in 'Additional Information' in Screenshot? Can you write it in english?

Comment: "An exception was thrown by the destination of a call" - good luck

Answer (score -2):

you must add username and password in to the database on connection string.